# Draw text on an angle (rotated) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, rotation, python-imaging-library

I am drawing text onto a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array image in Python (using a custom font). Currently I am converting the image to PIL, drawing the text and then converting back to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

char_image = np.zeros((200, 300, 3), np.uint8)

# convert to pillow image
pillowImage = Image.fromarray(char_image)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pillowImage)

# add chars to image
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 32)
draw.text((50, 50), 'ABC', (255, 255, 255), font=font)

# convert back to numpy array
char_image = np.array(pillowImage, np.uint8)

# show image on screen
cv2.imshow('myImage', char_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is there anyway to draw the text on a given angle, ie. 33 degrees?

Rotating the image once the text has been drawn is not an option

Comment: Have you tried using a library that allows drawing text on an angle, e.g. pangocairo?

Comment: Nope, seasoned programmer but fresh python newbie. Spent too much time reinventing the wheel and don't want to veer off on the wrong tangent so looking for some orthodox code I can dissect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using matplotlib, first visualize array and draw on it, get the raw data from the figure back.
Pro: both tools are quite high level and let you deal with many details of the process. [`ax.annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) offers flexibility for where and how to draw and set font properties, and [`plt.matshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow.html) offers flexibility that lets you deal with aspects of array visualization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

# make Data array to draw in
M = sp.zeros((500,500))

dpi = 300.0

# create a frameless mpl figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(M.shape[0]/dpi,M.shape[1]/dpi),dpi=dpi)
axes.axis('off')
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0,top=1.0,left=0,right=1)
axes.matshow(M,cmap='gray')

# set custom font
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
ttf_fname = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf'
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=ttf_fname)

# annotate something
axes.annotate('ABC',xy=(250,250),rotation=45,fontproperties=prop,color='white')

# get fig image data and read it back to numpy array
fig.canvas.draw()
w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
Imvals = sp.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(),dtype='uint8')
ImArray = Imvals.reshape((w,h,3))
```

[image]

Comment: This creates a funky background color and I am not sure where I can set the font.

Comment: @Bug I thought you wanted to draw on top of something so I just took some random numbers. Now its just replaced with zeros ...

Comment: Yeh sorry thats right, just got a little thrown. Thats a good trick with the random colors. Thanks for the update

Comment: That looks crisp. I know it wont look as clean but do you know if this can be done without anti-aliasing?

Comment: `plt.matshow()` uses no interpolation by default. You can change that with the keyword `interpolation=bilinear` (for example, see [here for more options](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow)). Edit: eeh I misunderstood you. I though you were asking for anti-aliasing (because right now, it shouldn't have any ... )

Comment: Basically I am using a binary image so either black or white, if you zoom in some edge pixels are gray. I can do this with thresholding but are wondering if there is a better way. Something like: interpolation=INTER_NEAREST

Comment: Thanks. I was just reading up on it, and it looks like it is caused by the font manager. How did you do it, with thresholding or did you find sth else?

Comment: I ended up using thresholding and it worked fine. I will spend some time tweaking everything from here

Answer (score 6):

You can use PIL to draw rotated text. I suggest drawing the text onto a blank image, rotating that image, and then pasting the rotated image into the main image.  Something like:

#### Code:

```
def draw_rotated_text(image, angle, xy, text, fill, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Draw text at an angle into an image, takes the same arguments
        as Image.text() except for:

    :param image: Image to write text into
    :param angle: Angle to write text at
    """
    # get the size of our image
    width, height = image.size
    max_dim = max(width, height)

    # build a transparency mask large enough to hold the text
    mask_size = (max_dim * 2, max_dim * 2)
    mask = Image.new('L', mask_size, 0)

    # add text to mask
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.text((max_dim, max_dim), text, 255, *args, **kwargs)

    if angle % 90 == 0:
        # rotate by multiple of 90 deg is easier
        rotated_mask = mask.rotate(angle)
    else:
        # rotate an an enlarged mask to minimize jaggies
        bigger_mask = mask.resize((max_dim*8, max_dim*8),
                                  resample=Image.BICUBIC)
        rotated_mask = bigger_mask.rotate(angle).resize(
            mask_size, resample=Image.LANCZOS)

    # crop the mask to match image
    mask_xy = (max_dim - xy[0], max_dim - xy[1])
    b_box = mask_xy + (mask_xy[0] + width, mask_xy[1] + height)
    mask = rotated_mask.crop(b_box)

    # paste the appropriate color, with the text transparency mask
    color_image = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, fill)
    image.paste(color_image, mask)
```

#### How does it work:

1. Create a transparency mask.
2. Draw the text onto the mask.
3. Rotate the mask, and crop to proper size.
4. Paste the desired color into the image, using the rotated transparency mask containing the text.

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

char_image = np.zeros((100, 150, 3), np.uint8)

# convert to pillow image
pillowImage = Image.fromarray(char_image)

# draw the text
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 32)
draw_rotated_text(pillowImage, 35, (50, 50), 'ABC', (128, 255, 128), font=font)

pillowImage.show()
```

#### Results:

[image: Results Image]

Comment: Have done some previous testing and found rotating the text after rasterization causes it to lose some of its shape so it is not as clean. Will use this method only if I cant find a way to rasterize an already rotated shape.

Comment: You should check these results.  With careful resampling the rasterization here is pretty good.

Comment: Will do, it is definitely a better method than what I am currently using (cv2.warpAffine)